# SQL query on many-to-many with redundant constraint

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Surprisely, I didn't found anything about my question. I hope I didn't looked for it too bad.

So, I got three tables, let's call them : Documents, Topics, and the many-to-many transitionnal table DocumentsTopics

I need to able to look for some Documents **that "contains" topic 8 and 15 only**. How do I do ? Because in the following example :

```
select Documents.title from Documents
inner join DocumentsTopics
on Documents.PK_DOC = DocumentsTopics.FK_DOC
inner join Topics
on DocumentsTopics.FK_TOPICS = Topics.PK_TOPICS

where Topics.PK_TOPICS=8 and Topics.PK_TOPICS=15;
```

The "where" is obviously impossible. Thanks a lot to those who can help !

Christophe

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). Things to consider: [exact division or division with remainder?](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/); how to handle an empty divisior (e.g. if the parts list to supply is the empty set, logically all suppliers can supply it but is it more practical to evaluate to no suppliers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I wasn't very clear in my description. But the solution I found out is to proceed by steps, without using only SQL, but with PHP.

I do a first reasearch with the first criterium :

```
where Topics.PK_TOPICS=8
```

I get the result in a PHP array. Then, a second one, with the second criterium :

```
where Topics.PK_TOPICS=15
```

I get the results in another, temporary PHP array.
And then I use PHP array_intersect() :

```
$results = array_intersect($results, $temp_results);
```

to find only the results that are matching both criteriums. Obviously, I can reuse $results to intersect as many time as I want. So, no limits to search criteriums.

Hope this help…

Answer (score 1):

If only documents where both topics 8 and 15 exist should be shown, then either of the below approaches (plus several more) work - check the query plan etc for performance.  The second performs better for me.

```
select distinct d.title
from Documents d
  inner join DocumentsTopics dt8 on dt8.fk_doc = d.pk_doc and dt8.fk_topics = 8
  inner join DocumentsTopics dt15 on dt15.fk_doc = d.pk_doc and dt15.fk_topics = 15

select d.title
from Documents d
where exists (select * from DocumentsTopics where fk_topics = 8 and fk_doc = d.pk_doc)
  and exists (select * from DocumentsTopics where fk_topics = 15 and fk_doc = d.pk_doc)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! the problem is that with OR, I will get all the Documents with Topic 8 and the ones with Topic 15, however, I would like to get only the Documents with Topics 8 AND 15.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Documents.title from Documents 
join DocumentsTopics on Documents.PK_DOC = DocumentsTopics.FK_DOC 
join Topics on DocumentsTopics.FK_TOPICS = Topics.PK_TOPICS
where Topics.PK_TOPICS=8 or Topics.PK_TOPICS=15;
```